# using featuretools to create "time window features"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, featuretools

I was trying to automate the creation of "row window features", using `featuretools` [package](https://docs.featuretools.com/index.html) but I couldn't find an easy way to create them. What I mean with "row window features" is that for each `cutoff` point I want to create features that extract time patterns. for example:

```
[columns] 
COUNT(orders) in 0to1 days    
COUNT(orders) in 1to2 days
COUNT(orders) in 2to3 days 
COUNT(orders) in 0to1 months    
...
```

I understand that there is a way to limit the "time window" for the features using the `training_window` parameter in `ft.dfs()`, but that's only a "lower bound"
it's there an easy way to create that kind of features ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it by using multiple cutoff times to set the "upper bound" of time. However, then your feature values for `COUNT(orders) in 0to1 days`, `COUNT(orders) in 1to2 days`, etc will be on the rows. You would then reshape the resulting dataframe to have them in the columns.

Comment: Thanks, using something like `pd.DataFrame.shift()` ?, it will be really helpful to have that feature implemented in `featuretools`